# How to insert Activity History record after sending an email

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, activities, send-email

I cannot create a new Activity History record when using   **message.setSaveAsActivity(true);**

so i added **mail.setTargetObjectId(con.id);**  its working fine.

**but actual issue is when i am sending mail to my gmail id its coming properly.
and when i am sending mail to my organization email id its coming multiple times.**

**e.g for 2 accounts sending mail to gmail id recieving 2 only. !!!working!!!
  for 2 accounts sending mail to my organization email id recieving 4. !!!multiple same      mails!!! 2 for each.**

This is my code:

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {recipient.Email};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setBccSender(true);
    String[] bccAddresses = new String[] {person.Email};
    mail.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(con.id);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(templateBody);
   Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The title of this question does not match your actual question and is misleading. You've solved the issue in the title in the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I know this may be 3 years late but in case someone else finds it useful. If you are sending the email to your own company email address, you may be getting duplicates because you have set the following to true;

```
    mail.setBccSender(true);
```

It basically means (when = true), when you send an email using the custom class, a copy will also be sent to your self, the sender.